# Meaning of xwEx for log4j2?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, log4j, log4j2

In Spring Boot 2.1.2, in the default `log4j2.xml` file, I noticed the following line:

```
<Property name="LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD">%xwEx</Property>
```

I have been searching for the meaning of the `%xwEx` conversion pattern all day (*yes, even the second page of Google*), but I can't figure it out. And it is not listed in the [table of patterns](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html) within the official documentation.

**What does it mean?**

Comment: It must be a valid conversion pattern, because otherwise log4j would throw an error (unrecognized format/conversion specifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to [Christoph](https://github.com/dreis2211) for the [answer on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15887#issuecomment-462130815):

> If I'm not mistaken this is a Spring-Boot specific converter plugin for log4j2. See [ExtendedWhitespaceThrowablePatternConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/ExtendedWhitespaceThrowablePatternConverter.java):
>
> ```
> @Plugin(name = "ExtendedWhitespaceThrowablePatternConverter", category = PatternConverter.CATEGORY)
> @ConverterKeys({ "xwEx", "xwThrowable", "xwException" })
> public final class ExtendedWhitespaceThrowablePatternConverter
>       extends ThrowablePatternConverter {
>     // ....
> }
> ```
>
> As I'm not a team member don't take this for granted though.
>
> Cheers,
>   Christoph